# how to centralize a textview inside of imageview android

Tags: android, xml

I have a LinearLayout and i just want to put a text at the middle of my imageview which is a shape.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/state_area"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#F000"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The result so far :

[image]

Comment: Use FrameLayout to wrap two views with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use a textview and set the shape as the background.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/state_area"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#F000"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: almost there, but the text is at the top, not at the center

Comment: add gravity=center

Comment: no problem, the other solutions will work as well and you might need to move to them as your view gets more complex.  But try to always keep it as simple as possible, it'll be better for performance in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Relative layout to arrange the layout on top of another.
Or your can use a custom circle drawable as the background to the textview

Comment: Relative layout would be a mess, i iwll try this textview background!

Answer (score 0):

```
Wrap your image and textview in framelayout 

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/shape"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/state_area"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#F000"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:gravity:"center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>



        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/shape"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/state_area2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#F000"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:gravity:"center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: almost there too, but the thing is, the text is not centralized, and yes at the top

Comment: add gravity="center" to textview